# Formatting columns in a pandas dataframe Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, format

The code below gets the `mean,median,max,min` as a pandas table. I just want to print the `Average` portion of the table without the dates. How would I be able to do that and get the expected output?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame

date_list = ['2019-09-01 00:00:00', '2019-10-01 00:00:00', '2019-11-01 00:00:00',
 '2019-12-01 00:00:00', '2020-01-01 00:00:00', '2020-02-01 00:00:00', 
 '2020-03-01 00:00:00', '2020-04-01 00:00:00', '2020-05-01 00:00:00', 
 '2020-06-01 00:00:00', '2020-07-01 00:00:00', '2020-08-01 00:00:00',
 '2020-09-01 00:00:00','2020-10-01 00:00:00', '2020-11-01 00:00:00', 
 '2020-12-01 00:00:00','2021-01-01 00:00:00','2021-02-01 00:00:00', '2021-03-01 00:00:00', 
 '2021-04-01 00:00:00','2021-05-01 00:00:00', '2021-06-01 00:00:00', 
 '2021-07-01 00:00:00']
monthly_values = np.array([ 15., 39.6, 0.2, 34.3, 19.6, 26.8, 15.7, 26., 12.6, 15.5, 18.6, 2.3, 6.5,
   2.5, 12.2, 11.6, 93.9, 25.5, 26.5, -16.5, -1.4, -1.8, 5.])

data = pd.DataFrame({"Date": date_list, "Averages": monthly_values})
data["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(data["Date"])
out=(data.groupby(data["Date"].dt.year)
     .agg(['mean','median','max','min'])
     .droplevel(0,1)
     .rename(columns=lambda x:'Average' if x=='mean' else x.title()))
print(out['Average'])
```

Output:

```
Date
2019    22.275000
2020    14.158333
2021    18.742857
```

Expected Output:

```
22.275000
14.158333
18.742857
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two columns named "Average", so `print(out["Average"])` prints both of them. To print just values from the second one:

```py
print(*out["Average"].iloc[:, 1], sep="\n")
```

Prints:

```
22.275
14.158333333333333
18.742857142857144
```

Comment: It gives me an error `IndexingError: Too many indexers`

Comment: @georgehere I used the script you have in your question. Can you post the data that gives you this error?

Comment: hello there sorry for the delayed response I am using the same thing too.